# How to test that a redux action has been called inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, jestjs, enzyme

I want to test that a redux action has been called inside useEffect.

I have my Root component as -

```
export default ({ children, initialState = {} }) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers, initialState, applyMiddleware(thunk))}>
      {children}
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

The  comonent as wrapped inside the  component-

```
import { clearState } from '../actions';
const App= (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    props.clearState();
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      App 
    </div>
  );
};

/**
 * Map the state to properties so that the component only
 * get relevant data.
 *
 * @param {object} state The current application state
 * @return {object} Data from the state that the component needs
 */
const mapStateToProps = () => {
  return {};
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  clearState
})(App);
```

My clearState action is as -

```
export const clearState = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CLEAR_STATE, payload: {} });
  };
};
```

I am trying to test that when the App component loads the clearState action is called.

```
const mockStore = configureStore([]);

describe('App component', () => {
  it('should call clearState action on component mount', () => {
    // Create a mock store
    const store = mockStore({});

    // Create a spy for the clearState action
    const clearStateSpy = jest.spyOn({ clearState }, 'clearState');

    // Mount the component with the Provider and store
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Root store={store}>
        <App/>
      </Root>
    );

    // Expect the clearState action to have been called
    expect(clearStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

But the test is failing as the number of calls is returning as 0. Any suggestion about what I am doing wrong will be of great help.

Answer (score 2):

`jest.spyOn` adds a "mock wrapper" to the original method, so you need to provide the module as an object to `jest.spyOn` and then during the test the component will use the method with "mock wrapper" imported from module that provided to `spyOn`.

```
import * as actions from '../actions' // here should be the path to the file where clearState action is located

const mockStore = configureStore([]);

describe('App component', () => {
  it('should call clearState action on component mount', () => {
    // Create a mock store
    const store = mockStore({});

    // here { clearState } was replaced with actions
    const clearStateSpy = jest.spyOn(actions, 'clearState'); 

    // Mount the component with the Provider and store
    const wrapper = mount(
      <Root store={store}>
        <App/>
      </Root>
    );

    // Expect the clearState action to have been called
    expect(clearStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```